# ErrorException in CompanyController.php line 126: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, controller

i am getting this error on my controller

my code is like this:

```
118 public function show($id)
119 {
120        $company_master = DB::table('tbl_company_master')->where('id', $id)->whereNull('tbl_company_master.deleted_at')->first();
121        $company_country = DB::table('tbl_countries')->select('*')->where('id',$company_master->country_id)->first();
122        $countries = DB::table('tbl_countries')->select('*')->orderBy('country_name', 'ASC')->whereNull('deleted_at')->where('status','1')->get();
123        $allstates = DB::table('tbl_states')->select('*')->orderBy('state_name', 'ASC')->where('country_id',$company_master->country_id)->whereNull('deleted_at')->
124                     where('status','1')->get();

125        $company_category = DB::table('tbl_company_industry_type')->where('industry_type_name',$company_master->company_category)->first();
126        $lawids = explode(",", $company_category->lm_id);
127        //dd($lawids);
128        $laws = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->whereNull('deleted_at')
129            ->where('status',1)
130            ->whereIn('id',$lawids)
131            ->get();
132        //dd($laws);

        $companyadmin = DB::table('users')->where('company_id', $id)->where('role', 6)->where('location_id', 0)->whereNull('deleted_at')->get();

        $company_master_class = "active open selected";
        return View::make('admin.companymaster.show')
            ->with('company_category', $company_category)
            ->with('company_master_class', $company_master_class)
            ->with('company_master', $company_master)
            ->with('allstates',$allstates)
            ->with('countries',$countries)
            ->with('company_country',$company_country)
            ->with('laws', $laws)->with('companyadmin', $companyadmin)
            ->with('get_company_details', $get_company_details);

         }
```

at line 126 i am getting an error as 
**Trying to get property of non-object**

what is the reason for this .?

Comment: check if `$company_category` is null or not.

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon yes erfan it is showing null when i do dd($company_category); but i have data on this table tbl_company_industry_type

Comment: check is this value string "$company_category->lm_id" or not, explode second param should be string, and check $company_category return value also

Comment: this does not exists... $company_category->lm_id
print_r($company_category) and see what comes

Comment: Then try to find why `$company_category` is returning null value. Check if `$company_master` also have a null value or not.

Comment: seem like $company_category is returning null.. please check the result.. use dd()

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon dd($company_master); returns me proper data but           i don;t know why dd($company_category); returns null value , i have data in table.

Comment: can you show me the return value of `dd($company_master)`. I guess I figure out where you are doing wrong. You are trying to access `$company_master->company_category` as if `$company_master` is an Object class but it's not. `$company_master` is a variable where you put the query result that returns an associative array. You may try  `$company_master['company_category']` something like this.

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon thanks a lot for helping me i have solved this error by changing $company_category as $company_category = DB::table('tbl_company_industry_type')->where('id',$company_master->company_category)->first();

Answer (score 1):

Please update your code like:

```
       $company_category = DB::table('tbl_company_industry_type')->where('industry_type_name',$company_master->company_category)->first();
        if(isset($company_category) && !empty($company_category)){
            $lawids = explode(",", $company_category->lm_id);
            //dd($lawids);
            $laws = DB::table('tbl_law_master')->whereNull('deleted_at')
                ->where('status',1)
                ->whereIn('id',$lawids)
                ->get();
            //dd($laws);
        } else {
            $laws = '';
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably, reason is code in line 125 can't find any matching line. Check if it is finding any **$company_category**